# How to find smallest tangent ellipse giving multiple lines ?

Tags: conic-sections

This ellipse must be tangent to at least 4 lines and it must intersect the other lines. I've tried to use ellipses that are parallel to the x- and y-axis. I've done this by transforming the equation of this lines into a dual space:

*l: px + qy + r = 0*  with *p<sup>2</sup> + q<sup>2</sup> = 1*

For a fixed ellipse, this can be transformed into:

*p<sup>2</sup>a<sup>2</sup> + q<sup>2</sup>b<sup>2</sup> - (px<sub>0</sub> + qy<sub>0</sub> + r)<sup>2</sup> = 0*

This has worked, but I'm just wondering how to find an ellipse that isn't parallel to the x- and y-axis in an elegant way. All types of suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have four lines. They determine a quadrilateral. Take the smallest of its two diagonals. The smallest ellipse touching all four sides is the degenerate ellipse coinciding with said diagonal, i.e., whose minor axis is zero, and whose major axis is the aforementioned diagonal. To visualize this, use [*GeoGebra*](http://web.geogebra.org/#algebra).

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your suggestion. But if I use this method, then I'll have to make combinations of 4 to calculate for every combination the smallest ellipse.  I was actually looking for a more general and more practical approach to solve this. But thanks anyway !